# Elements of array is always the last element inside a custom class using dot operator

Tags: java, arrays

Elements of array is always printing the last element of the array when i print them using a dot operator of the custom class after i pass the array as an argument inside the function ElePrint inside a custom class .

```
class ele {
    static int count, index, val;
    ele element[] = new ele[50];

    void ElePrint(int arr[], int n) {
        //Assign array values to the structure
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            element[i].val = arr[i];
        }
        for (int t = 0; t < n; t++) {
            System.out.print(" " + element[t].val);
        }
    }
}

class Hello {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ele el = new ele();
        int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
        int n = 6;
        el.ElePrint(arr, n);
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
6 6 6 6 6 6
```

But, what i want is the exact array

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Comment: `static int count, index, val;` should NOT be `static`

Comment: Please follow Java naming conventions :packages, attributes, variables, parameters, method have to start in lowerCase, and class in UpperCase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As `val` is static, it's unique in the class, every element of the `ele` class access the same object.

   So every `element[i].val` just access the `ele.val`, you need to remove the `static` and it'll be an attribute of each instance
2. Also, you created an array of `ele` object, but not the objects themselves, you need to

   ```
   element[i] = new ele();
   element[i].val = arr[i];
   ```

---

*Java naming conventions*

- name the class in UpperCamelCase, and use a significant name
- name the method in lowerCamelCase

Comment: Thank you so much @azro .The code worked absolutely perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are using `static` keyword with your class attributes. `static` keyword basically means that this variable is part of a class rather than an instance/object. Which means that whenever any object of this class modifies the value of `val` attribute, it will automatically be updated for other objects as well. That's why when you try to access the value of `val` attribute you get the latest value that is `6`.

Consider removing the `static` keyword from the declaration of `ele` class' attributes.